# Creating fields in the database

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, forms

I am newbie to wordpress plugin and this is my first plugin which I am doing now. I want that when the plugin will be activate it will make some predefined  fields in the database and also the same fields in the form page. So how to do that. Any help will be highly appriciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the WordPress codex, specifically http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API and if you are looking to create tables read http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins. Make sure you remove them if the plugin is uninstalled.